# Testing without external data?

Tags: test-management, test-design, test-data, php

The plugin, that I am writing in php, is getting data from an external api. I have gathered some sample-data which the api sends (array). Now I would like to create tests to make sure that the plugin is working properly when the main software is updated. **But it is not possible to make testing queries in production software to an external api.** How can I then use the gathered data for testing my software? Are there any patterns or tutorials, best practices? *(In some places the api query is in the middle of method/function?)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) the request to the API.

Here is a PHP example: https://github.com/InterNations/http-mock/blob/master/doc/start.md

What this example does, is start a small fake http server, which always returns that data that you expect/need for the test.

You can also start a seperate mock-server manually and use that to test against. Read more at http://www.mock-server.com/

Other reads:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268125/how-can-i-mock-an-external-web-request-in-phpunit